# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in UretimPlan.exe

Tags: c#, exception, sapb1

I'm developing a project to transfer selected rows between two datagridviews.
however, when I run the project and press the button that allows me to drop the selected rows from the parent table to the child table, I get the following error. I would be glad if you help.

[image: This view]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear(); 
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((bool)item.Cells[0].Value==true)
            {
                int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = ((DateTime)item.Cells[6].Value).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
               
            }
        }
    }
```

the error is in this line

```cs
dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = ((DateTime)item.Cells[6].Value).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Also, when I transfer the selected rows to the other table, I want it to be deleted from that table in my database. How can I do that ?

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVdue.png)

Comment: Would be good to know how the Cells[6].Value would look like. Probably it is not possible to cast it as DateTime Type

Comment: I added the picture. planlanan teslim tarihi is a date . How do I define this as a date

Comment: Well, how is it working without casting it to DateTime: item.Cells[6].Value.ToString(). Can you make a picture with this implemented and actual data inside the data grid

Answer (score 0):

> (DateTime)item.Cells[6].Value

This cast fails because either there is no value to cast, or the value is not a `DateTime`.

Is it a string maybe?